# $.getJSON with php file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, getjson

Hi guys :) I'm quite new in the programming world, so I really need your help. I tryed to get data from some database tables and unfortunately something goes wrong in my $.getJson() function . If i run the php file it works , and so that with the functions from script.js . My html is also ok so i suppose it is the $get.JSON fault. I don't know so many javascript , so i put all my hopes into you :*

html file:

```
 <!doctype html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <title>jQuery Ajax - PHP</title>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <script src="script.js"> 
 </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

script.js file :

```
$('document').ready( function() {
                                done();
                                }
                    );
function done() {
    setTimeout(function() { 
                         updates();
                         done();
                           }
              , 200 );
                 }
function updates(){ 
   $.getJSON( "read.php", function (data){

      $.each(data.array, function () {
          $("body").append("<li>Titlu: "+this['title']+"</li>
                            <li>Descriere: "+this['describtion']+"</li>");
                                     }
                           );

      $.each(data.array1, function () {
          $("body").append("<li>Id: "+this['id']+"</li>
                          <li>Category_Id: "+this['category_id']+"</li>
                          <li>Titlu: "+this['title']+"</li>
                          <li>Descriere: "+this['describtion']+"</li>");
                                        }
             );

    $.each(data.array2, function () {
        $("body").append("<li>Id: "+this['id']+"</li>
                          <li>Titlu: "+this['title']+"</li>
                          <li>Latitudine: "+this['location_latitude']+"</li>
                         <li>Longitudine:"+this['location_longitude']+"</li>
                         <li>Numar de telefon: "+this['phone_number']+"</li>
                          <li>Descriere: "+this['describtion']+"</li>");
                                     }
          );

    $.each(data.array3, function () {
        $("body").append("<li>Id: "+this['id']+"</li>
                    <li>Interest_point_id:"+this['interest_point_id']+"</li>
                    <li>Pret: "+this['price']+"</li>
                    <li>Data: "+this['event1_time']+"</li>");
                                      }
          );
                                          }
                );

              }
```

And finally the read.php file (Here it shows me what i expect , so i think everything is all right) :

```
<?php
include_once ('db.php');
$query= "SELECT * FROM category";
$query1= "SELECT * FROM sub_category";
$query2= "SELECT * FROM interest_point";
$query3= "SELECT * FROM event1";
global $connect;
$result =  mysqli_query($connect,$query);
$result1 = mysqli_query($connect,$query1);
$result2 = mysqli_query($connect,$query2);
$result3 = mysqli_query($connect,$query3);
$array = array();
$array1 = array();
$array2 = array();
$array3 = array();

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    array_push($array , array( 'id'          => $row[0],
                               'title'       => $row[1],
                               'describtion' => $row[2]
));

while($row1=mysqli_fetch_array($result1))
    array_push($array1 , array( 'id'         => $row1[0],
                               'category_id' => $row1[1],
                               'title'       => $row1[2],
                               'describtion' => $row1[3]

));
while($row2=mysqli_fetch_array($result2))
    array_push($array2 , array('id'                => $row2[0],
                               'title'             => $row2[1],
                               'location_latitude' => $row2[2],
                               'location_longitude'=> $row2[3],
                               'phone_number'      => $row2[4],
                               'describtion'       => $row2[5]

));
while($row3=mysqli_fetch_array($result3))
    array_push($array3 , array( 
                               'id'               => $row3[0],
                               'interest_point_id'=> $row3[1],
                               'price'            => $row3[2],
                               'event1_time'      => $row3[3]
));

    echo json_encode(array("array"=>$array)).'<br>'.'<br>';
    echo json_encode(array("array1"=>$array1)).'<br>'.'<br>';
    echo json_encode(array("array2"=>$array2)).'<br>'.'<br>';
    echo json_encode(array("array3"=>$array3)).'<br>'.'<br>';


?>
```

Comment: "Something goes wrong" is not a good explanation.  What goes wrong?

Comment: Please include error messages or any information from your logs about the `$.getJSON` call that's failing.

Answer (score 1):

You can only echo once when sending json and there can only be one php array containing all the data. You can't print anything outside of this such as the `<br>` tags

try changing

```
echo json_encode(array("array"=>$array)).'<br>'.'<br>';
echo json_encode(array("array1"=>$array1)).'<br>'.'<br>';
echo json_encode(array("array2"=>$array2)).'<br>'.'<br>';
echo json_encode(array("array3"=>$array3)).'<br>'.'<br>';
```

To

```
$output = array(
   "array1"=>$array1,
   "array2"=>$array2,
   "array3"=>$array3
);

echo json_encode($output);
```

Also note that `<li>` is an invalid child of `<body>`. Use `<div>` or insert into a `<ul>`

Comment: Thank you very much man :) It works now :D :D :D God bless you ! :*